# Resetear posición de un elemento cuando se realiza un drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Tengo un listado de elemento que se añaden dinámicamente y que son `draggable()`, tengo una región para el drop. Ahora bien, cuando hago el drop todo bien, pero la posición del elemento no se corresponde a la de donde esta en la región del drop(por ejemplo esquina superior izquierda que vendría siendo `top:0, left:0`), lo cual es lógico porque esa no es su posición original. Ahora, hay alguna forma de que cuando entre al drop la posición del elemento sea relativa al drop. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, incluye un [mcve] para que podamos ver el comportamiento que hay ahora.

Comment: Ok voy a tratar de montar un demo en codeopen... en cuanto este listo edito la pregunto. Gracias por la respuesta tan temprana

Comment: Puedes montar la demo directamente en Stack Overflow, hay un botón para añadir código (junto al botón de añadir imagen) que te permite añadir un snippet como JSFiddle o Codepen